# SceneKit collision didbegincontact change with Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode7, game-physics, scenekit

I have a SceneKit game that the character is set to collide and collect collectables within the game. This is done using the standard collision masks and was working perfectly until I updated to Xcode 7.

Now although the collision is happening the didbegincontact method is not being called.

Is there a change I missed to cause this? I have check the delegate declaration and reviewed changes made line by line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to set contactTestBitMask too, I usually do this:

```
b.contactTestBitMask = b.collisionBitMask
```

Comment: Perfect. Fixed instantly. This was made compulsory in iOS 9 something to be watched as even when deployment target of project is iOS 8 it causes issues on devices running iOS 9.